# why not allowed use var in grouping operator ()?

Tags: javascript

Excute this expression in console

```
(var a = 1)
```

Throw

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

In Ecma 11.1.6 The Grouping Operator

The production PrimaryExpression : ( Expression ) is evaluated as follows:
 1. Evaluate Expression. This may be of type Reference.
 2. Return Result(1).
I can't see ,why not allowed use var in ()?

And

```
(function b(){console.log(1)})
```

when excute `b` in the console , why throw b is not defined error`?

Comment: because it's not valid code...

Comment: `()` in your example could indicate an [**IIFE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which then would expect a function to be executed. This is valid `(function(){var a = 1;})`

Comment: @Fran: Actually you can wrap some statements (particularly evaluations or assignments) in brackets, but declaring variables in not permitted

Comment: `()` is the [*grouping operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) in this context where `var` is not legal

Comment: why this work ?(function a() {console.log(1)}) and after excute this expression, a is undefined why?

Comment: @musefan Yeah, I realized I was getting myself into an area I don't know all about when I posted the comment, so re-worded it slightly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648444/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-var)

Comment: @willChow asking why `a` is undefined in the example given in your previous comment is a different question which should probably be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

In javascript, variable declaration should not be enclosed within brackets().